# How to display data from file in specific format

Tags: python-3.x

I am taking an intro course on Python and trying to work through my last assignment but am getting stuck with the following task.

These are the contents of the .txt file I am reading and appending into an empty list:

```
Perry*Steve*80000
Smith*John*70000
Park*Sherri*85000
Straight*Amy*75000
Jones*Carol*82000
```

And the data has to display in the following format:

```
1. Jones, Carol: $82000
2. Park, Sherri: $85000
3. Perry, Steve: $80000
4. Smith, John: $70000
5. Straight, Amy: $75000
```

I am not sure how to go about doing this. I've tried .split("*") and .replace but no luck. Any ideas for an intro/beginner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After splitting on lines you can split on `*` and unpack into three variables:

```py
for line in s.split("\n"):
    first, last, dollars = line.split("*")
    print(f"{first}, {last}: ${dollars}")
```

Giving:

```py
Perry, Steve: $80000
Smith, John: $70000
Park, Sherri: $85000
Straight, Amy: $75000
Jones, Carol: $82000
```